# Dutch website blendle

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Holland we have this new service called 'Blendle'. I'm curious for the technique used behind the sideways scrolling. Let me elaborate.

If you visite their website on a desktop, laptop or tablet, scrolling is converted to sideways scrolling. How do they do that?
Furthermore, if you visite their website on a smartphone, their webpage suddenly doesn't scroll sideways anymore, but scroll vertical. How do they change that? Do they use bootstrap?

What are your opinions?

Comment: I'm it's quite easy to detect the browser and the device.

Comment: You are definitely not Dutch. Someone from the Netherlands would never refer to it as Holland, since these are just two provinces.

Comment: Ik ben wel degelijk Nederlands, het vloog er alleen sneller uit dan ik erover nadacht ;-)

Comment: URL is https://beta.blendle.nl (yet another site that will not gracefully degrade... No JS, not a single news). Inspect code with DevTools/Firebug to see if they're using Media Queries or JS to detect resolution, etc SO isn't about opinions, only about questions related to programming with some code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Blendle probably use some Bootstrap plugin or function, I know a way to accomplish this with jQuery and the **[jQuery Mousewheel plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/)**.

First load jQuery and the plugin.

Then initiate with the following code (note you might want to replace `$('.container')` to correspond with your containing element. If you have no container, put `$('html,body')`.

```
<script>
(function($){
    $('.container').on('mousewheel', function(event,delta){
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sideways scrolling: jquery animate http://api.jquery.com/animate/

As for the differences between mobile and desktop versions, you can define those using mediaqueries (css).

Google both and you'll find a lot :)

edit: I don't know if it's possible to PM on stackoverflow, but if it is, please do. I'm also dutch and I think I can explain a lot more in our both native language ;p